# Young-Tableau Exercise Solution Help

Tags: young-tableaux

i have the following definition of a young tableau:
A Young tableau is an m × n matrix ($t_{i,j}$) with entries from N ∪ {∞}, for which it holds that in each row and each column the values ascend from left to right and from top to bottom, respectively. The entries with value ∞ stand for empty places.

Task: Specify a 3 × 3 Young tableau with entries 4, 16, 7, 1, 9.

Here is my Solution:
$$\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline 1 & 4 & 7 \\ \hline 9 & 16 & ∞ \\ \hline ∞ & ∞ & ∞ \\ \hline  \end{array}$$
but im not sure, if it should look like this:

$$\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline 1 & 4 & 7 \\ \hline 4 & 7 & 9 \\ \hline 7 & 9 & 16 \\ \hline  \end{array}$$

based on the given description, both could be possible. But after i looked up the wikipedia article, it seems that it is not common for such a tableau to hold two numbers with the same value. Therefore I think solution 1 is the correct one.

So I'm quite confused. Maybe someone can give me a hint.

Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The first tableau is the good one.